# Finding protected questions

Tags: discussion, support, search, protection

How do I find the list of protected questions?

I've seen a couple of protected questions for which I could not see a reason for protection and I'd like to find more.

Comment: On the few occasions that I've protected a Question, it was not based on the intrinsic characteristics of the Question but [on the history of spam or rude "answers" that it had attracted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20333/protect-questions-practical-reasons) (driven, it seems to me, by the popularity/upvotes of the Question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Users with 10K reputation can access the [Protected Questions list](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions).

You can find this by going through the "review" link in the top bar, then choose the "Tools" tab and then the "stats" subtab, and finally looking at the "Links" towards the bottom of the page.

The [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) can also be employed to find protected questions via the `PostHistory` table. [Here's a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/670935/latest-100-protected-questions-which-havent-been-unprotected) which gives the 100 latest questions to be protected which haven't been since unprotected (modulo the last data dump).